# 400 Bad Request for djoser based registered user activation

Tags: django, authentication, postman, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, djoser

I am new to django and am trying to build a use registration system using djoser, I am getting the email for activation but the activation process is not working

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
# Create your models here.


class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for art_portal project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "***"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "app",
    "rest_framework",
    "djoser",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "art_portal.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build')],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "art_portal.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'auth_system',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",},
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "app.UserAccount"



EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'asf@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '***'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',), 
}

DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SET_USERNAME_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'activation': 'djoser.serializers.ActivationSerializer',
        'user_create': 'app.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'app.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    }
}


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.UserAccount'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build/static')
]
```

serializers.py

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'name', 'password')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from . import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
]

urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
```

and this is the json req that i am trying to send to http://localhost:8000/auth/users/activation/ via postman

```
{
    "uid":"Mg",
    "token":"bqqeu2-20ca93a0ce0fec08211744b0a6a92ea5"
}
```

but i am getting a 400 saying:

```
  File "/Users/***/Desktop/aef/backend/proj_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa:8000'. You may need to add '1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Bad Request: /auth/users/activation/
[03/Jul/2023 01:46:15] "POST /auth/users/activation/ HTTP/1.1" 400 65414
```

P.S. adding `1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa` to allowed hosts is not helping either.

Comment: Try to add: '.1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa', '*'

Comment: Hello @Marin thanks for your reply, when i do that, it says: Bad Request: /auth/users/activation/
[03/Jul/2023 14:00:45] "POST /auth/users/activation/ HTTP/1.1" 400 71
[03/Jul/2023 14:00:45] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('{')
[03/Jul/2023 14:00:45] "{" 400 -

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS = [".1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa", "*"]

Comment: @Marin Yes i did that.. in settings.py and i got the error as mentioned in my above comment in postman

Comment: Then check you JSON for POST request

message Bad request syntax ('{')